# Windows 8 Mail - Storage Folder Location

Tags: windows-8

Does anyone know of where Windows 8 Mail app store inbox data? I'm trying to find a way if it is possible to import my Outlook 2010's PSTs (or EMLs) into this folder location. I tried looking into my user account's `appdata` folder but couldn't find anything useful.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I highly suspect that just dumping your  PST or EML into that folder isn't going to work. Search for an export/import option instead.

Comment: There's no export/import option for this app. I don't plan to dump PST or EML files into this location, but just want to see what kind of files it contains and if some secondary app could be written to add PST/EML backup to this location.

Comment: Have you tried using procmon?

Comment: @Zishan I am not convinced W8 mail stores anything locally, its a mail reader, Install Windows Live Mail if you want to POP and store email locally.

Comment: @Moab There is no Windows Live Mail anymore. Thought you installed the "Live Mail", it refused to run in Windows 8.

Comment: @Jagd yes there is, it is part of Live Essentials package....http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/Windows-Essentials-2012-system-requirements

Comment: Download here...http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-live/essentials-other-programs

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be what you're after, it's for Outlook 2003 but mentions PST files so fingers crossed:

http://www.forumswindows8.com/general-discussion/import-outlook-2003-windows-8-a-1063.htm

> You need to go to Control Panel /mail **bit/Double click and if your
>   Outlook is configured you will see your profile. Double clic the
>   profile and add the data file (pst) (Browse to folder that you copied
>   it).
>
> If you did not create a new Outlook account, open Outlook then close
>   it without creating account. Go to controll panel / find mail ** bit,
>   double clic, create a profile and browse for your data file that you
>   copied to another drive.

Answer (score 1):

I did a search for files looking like 'mail' changed today and found the location at

```
C:\Users\[machine name]\AppData\Local\Packages\microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\Indexed\LiveComm\a0ba5af4dd39597b\120712-0049\Mail\7e\
```

I suggest having a look... somewhere down that tree. Files are `.eml` and they open in Outlook.